# How to pass C++ exceptions through functions compiled with LibJIT?

Tags: c++, exception, jit

I'm using LibJIT to JIT-compile a programming language. My compiler is written in C++, so I have a C++ program calling the LibJIT library, which is written in C.

In my C++ code I have some functions that throw exceptions, and sometimes these get triggered on the far side of a LibJIT-compiled function. That is, my C++ program uses LibJIT to compile a function, calls it, and the JIT-compiled function in turn calls a C++ function that throws an exception. But instead of the exception being propagated back through the JIT-compiled function to my handler, the runtime calls `std::terminate`.

Apparently the exception-handling mechanism needs each function in the call stack to implement some kind of exception support. When compiling C code, the `-fexceptions` flag tells the compiler (at least gcc) to include this support.

**Is there a way to include this exception support in my LibJIT-generated functions?**

I tried using the LibJIT instructions to set up a "catcher" block that rethrows all exceptions, but that didn't work; it looks like the LibJIT's exception-handling model is separate from the C++ model.

Obviously I don't really want to throw C++ exceptions into my language's code, and I'll have to figure out some other error-handling strategy. But I'm wondering if it's even possible to get it to work.

Here's a sample program that demonstrates the issue. I'm sorry it's this long but LibJIT is pretty low-level so you have to write a lot of code to get anything done. I'm compiling on Linux with clang 10.0.0.

```
#include <array>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <jit/jit.h>

class ex : public std::exception {};

extern "C" int bad(int arg) {
  std::cout << "Called with arg=" << arg << std::endl;
  throw ex();
}

jit_function_t build_function(jit_context_t context) {

    // The signature of the compiled function and "bad" are the same.
    std::array<jit_type_t, 1> params{jit_type_int};
    jit_type_t signature = jit_type_create_signature(jit_abi_cdecl, jit_type_int, params.data(), params.size(), 1);

    jit_function_t function = jit_function_create(context, signature);
    jit_value_t arg_value = jit_value_get_param(function, 0);
    jit_value_t bad_value =
        jit_value_create_nint_constant(function, jit_type_void_ptr, (reinterpret_cast<jit_nint>(bad)));
    std::array<jit_value_t, 1> bad_args{arg_value};
    jit_value_t result = jit_insn_call_indirect(function, bad_value, signature, bad_args.data(), bad_args.size(), 0);
    jit_insn_return(function, result);

    jit_function_compile(function);

    return function;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    // This exception will be caught:
    try {
      bad(7);
    } catch (const ex&) {
      std::cout << "Caught exception from direct call" << std::endl;
    }

    // Initialize libjit.
    // We're single-threaded so not going to bother with jit_context_build_start/jit_context_build_end.
    jit_init();
    jit_context_t context = jit_context_create();

    jit_function_t function = build_function(context);

    // This one will not be caught, calls std::terminate instead:
    try {
      int (*closure)(int) = reinterpret_cast<int (*)(int)>(jit_function_to_closure(function));
      closure(7);
    } catch (const ex&) {
      std::cout << "Caught exception from libjit call" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Called with arg=7
Caught exception from direct call
Called with arg=7
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ex'
  what():  std::exception
Aborted
```

Comment: Having an exception propagate from an `extern "C"` function is undefined behavior in C++. Given that `libJIT` is written in C and trying to call an `extern "C"` function, I don't see how it could even be possible to propagate an exception in this scenario _at all_. I don't even believe `-fexceptions` would change this. You _might_ be able to get this to work if `libJIT` was compiled with `-fexceptions` -- but AFAIK this would still be UB.

Comment: You could catch the exception in the funcion with the C calling conventions, signal the error condition via return value or pointer to a status parameter and then throw a new exception with that information from the C++ function.

Comment: @Human-Compiler The fact that LibJIT itself is written in C shouldn't matter. It's compiling some other language, which could be C++. In fact the question could have been, would it be possible to use LibJIT to compile a C++ function and have it be able to catch exceptions thrown by (or throw exceptions to) a C++ function compiled with Clang or GCC?

Comment: @MarkusLenger That's what I wound up doing, catching the exception and translating it to LibJIT's own exception-handling facility.